# console program for php

Tags: php

In Chrome Developer Tools there is a console which I can write any javascript function or method and get result instantly. That's very useful and practical to know how a function, method works.

Is there something similar for PHP? without the need to save a file and open it in browser?

Comment: Consider using unit testing, PHPUnit. But it is more appropriate when having experience and more complex code...meanwhile refresh the browser...

Comment: Ok. I edited to be more specific. Can you remove the on hold?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need a sandbox playground like:

- http://tehplayground.com/
- http://3v4l.org/ (Even runs your script on multiple versions of PHP so you can compare output)

---

If your code is more coupled to a particular project or has dependancies which can't be loaded in a web sandbox you could use unit tests as suggested by @KA_lin.

Comment: I always used writecodeonline.com/php but now is down, the two links are good choices

Answer (score 2):

The PHP command line interface has a built-in interactive shell. Just run `php -a` and type in your commands.

Comment: I didn't know about -a, i used -r to execute code, but I'm on windows with xampp so I don't have that

Comment: I finally could make it to work in phpstorm. I created a file in a test folder, added to ide include paths, wrote the code, created a run configuration with interpreter options -f, and run it, and I saw the result in run tab without open the browser